# rails sprockets get asset's digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, digest

what is the easiest way to get an asset's digest in ralis?

for example here is the javascript file

```
javascript_path "jquery.js"
```

and I wonder what is the digest for this `jquery.js`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the environment object exposed at `Rails.application.assets` to get more information about your assets, as in:

```
Rails.application.assets['jquery'].digest # => "a7570eab23993d2a207ddaa1b55756c6"
Rails.application.assets['jquery'].digest_path # => "jquery-a7570eab23993d2a207ddaa1b55756c6.js"
```

Comment: Awesome answer, been looking for hours for this solution. Please note that to get this to work for angular lazy load, I had to name the file something like app.js.erb and include a tag like: 
    <%= 'assets/' + Rails.application.assets['templates/directives/header/header'].digest_path %>